# mpi4py send and receive by the same process

Tags: python, mpi

I have 4 processes and they communicate with each other.

Each process runs two threads simulataneously:

- thread 1 to send messages
- thread 2 to receive messages

There are also situations when a process sends the message to itself. i.e. process Pi's thread 1 sends message to Pi's thread 2.

I have implemented send using isend and have written a non-blocking receive. But I noticed that Pi's thread 2 is unable to receive message sent by Pi's thread 1.

I am using mpi4py python module to model this. Can I model this with minimal changes to the existing structure of the code

Comment: The communication has to be asynchronous.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: MPI provides several types of send/recv operations. The basic ones are synchronous: the `send` function only returns when all the data has been sent; while the asynchronous ones don't.

Comment: I am using isend and have implemented a non blocking receive. Still the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure folks can answer your question as asked.  Can you post code, and tell us what result you're expecting to get, and what result you're actually getting?

Comment: Do you have a thread-safe MPI implementation and do you initialise it properly (in the C API - call `MPI_Init_thread` with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`)? If you use Open MPI, it has to be compiled in a special way in order to have full multithreading support. Also, do you call `MPI_Wait` or whatever the mpi4py equivalent to complete all asynchronous requests? By the way, why use non-blocking operations when you have separate threads of execution (unless what you do is overlap communication with computation)?

Comment: Adding your code would help tremendously